# Why docker-compose fail and docker run success with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am tring to start a postgreSQL docker container with my mac;  i use OSX 10.11.16 El Capitan with Docker Toolbox 19.03.01.

If i run:

```
docker run --name my_postgres -v my_dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 54320:5432 postgres:11
```

all was done and i get:

> my_postgres | 2019-09-17 04:51:48.908 UTC [41] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

but if i use an .yml file like this one:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:11"
    container_name: "my_postgres"
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
    volumes:
      - my_dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  my_dbdata:
```

and run

```
docker-compose up
```

i get instead:

> my_postgres | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
>   my_postgres | 
>   my_postgres | 2019-09-17 04:51:49.009 UTC [41] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
>   my_postgres | 2019-09-17 04:51:49.011 UTC [41] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
>   my_postgres | waiting for server to shut down....2019-09-17 04:51:49.087 UTC [41] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 48) exited with exit code 1
>   my_postgres | 2019-09-17 04:51:49.091 UTC [43] LOG:  shutting down
>   my_postgres | 2019-09-17 04:51:49.145 UTC [41] LOG:  database system is shut down

Why the same think with docker-compose fail?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: what is inside "my_dbdata" , I think it is empty

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one it worked for me

```
version: '3.1'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  restart: always
  environment:
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
  volumes:
    - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

Then use `docker-compose up` to get the logs after using the previous command use
`docker-compose logs -f`

Comment: i get:db_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1  | 
db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:05:14.746 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:05:14.749 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:05:14.751 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:05:14.902 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-09-17 05:05:14 UTC

Comment: db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:05:14.995 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:06:39.504 UTC [1] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:06:39.608 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:06:39.618 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
db_1  | 2019-09-17 05:06:39.662 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
testpost_db_1 exited with code 0

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access and existing volume on the host machine, you need to specify that the volume was created outside the Compose file with the `external` keyword like this:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data:
    external: true
```

I took the example from the Compose file reference https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/.

Also double check the contents of your external volume between runs, to see if it was overriden.

Please also double check your quotes, you don't need to put the image name in quotes, but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: (Without `external: true` Compose will include the directory name as part of the volume name, so the two forms in the question reference different volumes.)

Answer (score 0):

The `my_dbdata` named volume is not the same for the two cases. 
`docker run` creates a volume named `my_dbdata`, instead `docker-compose` creates by default a volume called `<dir>_my_dbdata`

Run `docker volume` to list the volumes:

```
docker volume ls |grep my_dbdata
```

I suspect the volume created by `docker-compose` has issues and as a consequence `postgres` doesn't start correctly. The initialization of the database in the `my_postgres` container is done only once.

Try to remove the container and the volume created by `docker-compose`:

```
docker rm my_postgres
docker volume rm <dir>_my_dbdata
```

Hope it helps